# How to Automate xamarin TimePicker

Tags: c#, xamarin, android-uiautomator

I am new to Mobile testing
Currently I am using xamarin UI to automate mobile UI test

I followed DatePicker from below link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/frameworks/uitest/features/date-time-pickers

My TimePicker UI looks like as in image
I should scroll and update required time
[TimePicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KkNK7.jpg)automatically like what we have for DatePicker.
Thank’s in advance.

I tried to get text of element that is visible and Applied ScrollDown on it. ScrollDown is not scrolling as expected.
Any suggestions, links will help me.

Comment: The article you linked to has examples for DatePicker and TimePicker.